# Docker container not starting. Permission denied on Entrypoint

Tags: linux, shell, docker, raspberry-pi

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nilbro/rover-api AS builder-myapp
WORKDIR /home/dev/
COPY ./driving_control_iotplayground/src/driving_control.cpp /home/dev/driving_control.cpp
RUN sudo g++ -lroverapi -o driving_control driving_control.cpp

#Building everything
#FROM balenalib/raspberrypi3-alpine
FROM balenalib/raspberrypi3
#FROM raspbian/stretch
WORKDIR /app/

# Add driving_control
COPY --from=builder-myapp /home/dev/driving_control /app/driving_control

RUN ["chmod","+x","/app/driving_control"]

# general libs
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/lib/libwiringPi.so /usr/lib/libwiringPi.so
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so /usr/lib/libwiringPiDev.so
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libhono_interaction.so /usr/local/lib/libhono_interaction.so
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1 /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1 /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1 /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1 /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjsoncpp.so.1 /usr/local/lib/


# roverapi libs
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libconfig_reader.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libpthread_distribution.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libroverapi.so  /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libroverapptasks.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libtiming.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libhono_interaction.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libpthread_monitoring.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libroverappdrivers.so /usr/local/lib/
COPY --from=builder-myapp /usr/local/lib/libstatus_library.so /usr/local/lib/

RUN ldconfig

# Start driving_control
ENTRYPOINT ["./driving_control"]
```

The image is generated. However running the container from the image with volume mounts throws the following error:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"./driving_control\": permission denied": unknown.
```

The docker run command I am using is:

```sh
docker run -v $(pwd):/root/workspace/driving_control -w 
/root/workspace/driving_control -it arm32v6/rover-app:0.0.1 /bin/bash
```

There are no issues when there are no volume mounts.
I would be grateful if someone helps me out with this.

Comment: What exactly are you mounting where?  Can you show your actual `docker run` command?  If you’re mounting something over your `/app` directory, then you’re not running the code that’s in the image and you’re fairly likely to hit this class of problem.

Comment: docker run -v $(pwd):/root/workspace/driving_control -w /root/workspace/driving_control -it arm32v6/rover-app:0.0.1 /bin/bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like setting permission is not setting properly in `RUN` command.

Try this

```
RUN chmod +x /app/driving_control
```

**RUN**
RUN  has 2 forms:

> ````
> default is /bin/sh -c on Linux or cmd /S /C on Windows)
>
> RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form)```
> ````

[dockerfile-syantax-RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

**Update:**

you are override everything inside docker image on this path `/root/workspace/driving_control`. try to remove mount path, as you already have on docker image, as also mentioned by @David

So update your docker run command to

```
docker run -v  -w /root/workspace/driving_control -it arm32v6/rover-app:0.0.1
```

Comment: @David comment make sense, how you start the container? are you using docker-compose or docker run?

Comment: you are verride everything inside docker image on this path `v $(pwd):/root/workspace/driving_control`. try to remvoe mount path, as you already have on docker iamge

Comment: great. You do not need to map the host files once you copy to docker image.